# Writing-Reading a hashtable to a text file

Tags: programming-practices, data-structures, hashing, serialization

I'm implementing a hashtable structure for a dictionary. Dictionary is in a text file. There are 2 words on each line. I'm generating the hashtable by using the first word as a key. I'm holding the hashtable on a list. I want to save the hashtable to a text file to use it every time. What kind of structure should I use? Is there a way to do this without reading the whole hashtable from text file?

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense.   You're building a hashtable from a dictionary file - why do you need another file?

Comment: to save the hashtable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

In Python you could use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html). In Java [you can do it too](http://java.sys-con.com/node/44199). Almost every language has techniques for serialization.

If your hashtable becomes too big, you will have to use a [relational database management sysyem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDBMS), like MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.

Comment: Binary serialization can be a big pain, particularly if objects change over time. This leaves us with textual serialization, which should be ... just a CSV file with two columns : key and value :)

Comment: That's what I thought too, but maybe for some reason she doesn't want to read or write the CSV again.